# How to determine current zoom percentage when using StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL?

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming, stage

Currently, I am creating a Flash application using ActionScript 3. My `stage.scaleMode` is set to `StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL`, so that my app is automatically zoomed to fit contents of the stage.

The problem is I don't know how to get the current zoom percentage.

Comment: Finally, I accomplished the same by alternative way. I instead of using,
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL, used
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE
and manually scaled the root to achieve zoom.
Doing this, I now have zoomlevel known :). Hope this helps anyone with similar problem.

Comment: I wonder if say `stage.scaleX` reading would return the correct zoom. You say you've searched, but did you try the stage's unusual implementation of these properties?

Comment: @Vesper - unfortunately if using SHOW_ALL, the stage won't even know it is resized - there won't be resize event, and both width and scaleX would return the same values as the originals. It's pretty awkward behavior and I don't know who uses that :)

Answer (score 2):

`StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL` is a bit tricky. I usually use `NO_SCALE` and manually do all the trick, pretty much like how it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466513/how-to-get-the-stage-dimensions-with-stagescalemode-show-all).

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just writing this as you posted your comment.. It's good you came up with the solution.. Cheers!